# How to select the language of a Windows 8 upgrade downloaded from the MS Store

Tags: windows-8

I want to purchase a Windows 8 upgrade through the Microsoft Store. When I visit the store, I get forcibly redirected to its German incarnation (probably because I am in Germany). However, I can only select another language when selecting the option to get a DVD sent to me (which is 30 EUR more expensive):

[image: "Englisch" under "Produktsprache?"]

If I selected the "Download" option, I would be forced to get a German version:

[image: language choice field is grayed out for downloads]

So is there a way to purchase another language as download (in my case it'd be English)?

Comment: Try an US SSL web proxy?(only for the purchasing part) never tried though

Comment: Could you please provide the link to this store?

Comment: I think this is it: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/de_DE/pdp/productID.256400400 but "Download starten" links to http://windows.microsoft.com/buy with no country code or is it just me?

Comment: This is a good question, but after reading it a couple times, I realized it wasn't a good fit for SU. You could replace Windows 8 in the question with any product, and have basically the same question. You're asking about how to use a specific website, which is off-topic here, regardless of the product you're trying to buy. I'm glad you found a satisfactory workaround, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading the Upgrade Advisor from the US English store site. Payment was done through a German company within the upgrade, but I indeed ended up with a UK English Windows, which is close enough to comfortable for me.

Comment: This happened to me as well. My Windows is US English, I ran the Upgrade Assistant in Spain, and what I ended up with is UK English. Not exactly what I intended. I'd like to know if it's possible to select the language *without* having to resort to installing language packs. I'm thinking maybe a VPN tunnel with an IP from USA might do the trick.

Comment: Well, 150 MiB of additional download and a reboot doesn't hurt too much, I guess.

Comment: Download size has nothing to do. I just want things to be as streamlined as possible; the less I have to do to setup a computer, the better. Besides, installing a language pack doesn't render the same result as installing Windows in the desired language directly. At least in my experience, some things -like text in the welcome screen for example- remain in the original language, even after specifically making the desired language the default.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all versions of Windows 8 comes with a Language Pack. You can download the German or English version and then select the desired language once you've booted the installer.

[image]

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Comment: Correct, see this section "switch languages on the fly"....[see this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx)

Comment: It appears only  China and a small set of select emerging markets will have regional restrictions....[see this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-here-are-the-four-editions-of-windows-8/12461)

Comment: Moab, language packs are something you install *after* installing Windows in a particular language (like you could with Windows 7 Enterprise). This still leaves certain things in the original language, e.g. symlinks in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an ugly workaround, but it will work: download the English Windows 8 from thepiratebay or some other P2P, and buy the German version in the store, and use THAT key when you install the English Windows 8 from your bootable usb. It's just as fast, if not faster- I've used Microsoft's secure download manager, even had issues with them, so that's the way I solved my problem with OBTAINING Windows 8. My product key, however is perfectly legit, so I'm not advocating piracy ;)

Comment: definitely ugly and possibly illegal depending on where you live.

Comment: There's no guarantee those files are unaltered. You could be downloading embedded malware for all you know.

Comment: @Bob You could check the sha1 with the MSDN website.

Comment: @Moab The key is what makes Windows legal.

Comment: @kinokijuf a lot of pirated copies have embedded activation cracks which will throw off hash checking. Also, a hash collision is possible, though difficult. That's all ignoring questionable legality.

Comment: @Bob I was talking about checking the hash of the ISO. SHA1 has not been broken yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some simple steps in your control panel.Check out here...
http://www.youngnerves.com/tag/windows-8-language-support/

Comment: Already known and suggested in the comments. The actual reason why this is a poor solution is noted in some comments as well.